# Is there a linear/mixture function that can fit the Gartner hype curve?

Tags: normal-distribution, curve-fitting, logarithm, quadratic-form

The Gartner hype curve:

> is a branded graphical presentation developed and used by American information technology (IT) research and advisory firm Gartner for representing the maturity, adoption and social application of specific technologies.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hype_cycle

And it looks like this:

[image]

**Is there a function that can fit this curve?** If not, what would be the closest approximation of the function that can fit this curve?

The first part of the curve looks like a gaussian/normal distribution and the second part looks like a partial quadratic function and the last partlooks like a right tail of the logarithm curve.

Answer (score 6):

There is no formally defined curve, just a picture. However, the picture suggests a curve that passes the [vertical line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test), and hence could be defined by a function. You could construct a simple function that looks like the picture with a generic curve-fitting method such as cubic splines.

I might add that this all seems like a pointless exercise because the hype cycle isn't a representation of any empirical data or mathematical object. It's just a picture that's drawn to look like a graph, presumably to mislead readers into thinking it's somehow scientific or quantitative. One might call it a fake graph.

Comment: Do you mind updating the post with R code to produce the plot?

Comment: @zx8754 That's not really on-topic for this site. Try Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agree, didn't want to duplicate the post, in case you had an R code ready.